# Why uploading multi files to google drive shows Untitled file?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Currently, I use google script's form to update customer information as well as customer attachments. All files will be saved to Google drive. The problem here is that if I use upload files one by one, there is no error. But when I upload many files at once, I often get an error like:

**1** In my Google drive, along with the file I uploaded, an Untitled file appears
**2** Sometimes the file upload fails
**3** And if you use your phone to submit the form, you can only get the data, the attached file will not be saved to Google drive
Is there any way to solve the above error?

[image: My drive]

### Google Script Part

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}
function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);

    var dropbox = "添付ファイル"; // Folder Name
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    var file = folder.createFile(ss);

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Error: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
function doPost(e) {
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  
  var destination_id = '1BBwRBt4dVvjRN9-qlxV-87oo5GJECOyM';  // ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE DIRECTORY;
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id);
  
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameter.fileData);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameter.mimeType, e.parameter.fileName);
  destination.createFile(blob);
  
  listRecord(e.parameter.applicationDate
            ,e.parameter.name
            ,e.parameter.department
            ,e.parameter.usingDepartment
            ,e.parameter.PurchasedItemForm3
            ,e.parameter.cost
            ,e.parameter.privateCost
            ,e.parameter.remarksForm3
            ,e.parameter.fileName); 
  
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  htmlOutput.message = 'File Uploaded';
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();                              
   

      
}

function listRecord(applicationDate,name,department,usingDepartment, PurchasedItemForm3,privateCost,cost,remarksForm3,filename )
{
   var newCheckbox = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
  newCheckbox.requireCheckbox()
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build()
  if(usingDepartment=="管理部"){
  var url = URL;  //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("管理シート");
  recordsSheet.appendRow(["",new Date(),applicationDate,name,department,usingDepartment,"その他経費","","","",cost,"","","","","","","","","","",PurchasedItemForm3,remarksForm3,cost,privateCost ]);
  recordsSheet.getRange(recordsSheet.getLastRow(), 1).setDataValidation(newCheckbox);

  }else if(usingDepartment=="営業部"){
    var url = URL;  //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("管理シート");
    recordsSheet.appendRow(["",new Date(),applicationDate,name,department,usingDepartment,"その他経費","","","",cost,"","","","","","","","","","",PurchasedItemForm3,remarksForm3,cost,privateCost ]);
    recordsSheet.getRange(recordsSheet.getLastRow(), 1).setDataValidation(newCheckbox);

  }else if(usingDepartment=="業務部"){
    var url = URL;  //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("管理シート");
    recordsSheet.appendRow(["",new Date(),applicationDate,name,department,usingDepartment,"その他経費","","","",cost,"","","","","","","","","","",PurchasedItemForm3,remarksForm3,cost,privateCost ]);
    recordsSheet.getRange(recordsSheet.getLastRow(), 1).setDataValidation(newCheckbox);
  }
  else if(usingDepartment=="製造部"){
    var url = URL;  //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("管理シート");
    recordsSheet.appendRow(["",new Date(),applicationDate,name,department,usingDepartment,"その他経費","","","",cost,"","","","","","","","","","",PurchasedItemForm3,remarksForm3,cost,privateCost]);
    recordsSheet.getRange(recordsSheet.getLastRow(), 1).setDataValidation(newCheckbox);

  }
}

function getUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}
```

### HTML CODE

```html
   <body>
      <?var url = getUrl();?>
      <form method="post" action="<?= url ?>" >
         <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6">
      <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <h1 style="color:#7c795d">その他経費<br>（事務用品など）</h1>
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="applicationDate">申請日</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="applicationDate" name="applicationDate">
      <script>
         var date = new Date();
         var day = date.getDate();
         var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
         var year = date.getFullYear();
         if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
         if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
         var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
         document.getElementById('applicationDate').value = today;
      </script>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
      <label for="department">各部門<span style="color: red;font-weight:bold">*</span></label>
      <select name="department" id="id_department" data-child-id='id_child' class='dependent-selects__department' required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>選択...</option>
      <option value="管理部" data-child-options="宮元会長|#宮元社長|#監査役|#取締役|#岡本|#三宅">管理部</option>
      <option value="営業部" data-child-options="西村　英治|#杉田　哲朗|#南　洋志|#大西　美香|#知場　亜伊子|#竹田　有香|#田川　真弓">営業部</option>
      <option value="業務部" data-child-options="松本　嘉朗|#韓|#前川|#ジェシー|#ドウエン|#島田　航|#ヒエップ">業務部</option>
      <option value="製造部" data-child-options="長崎　義則|#樋口　優子|#島田　亮|#木下">製造部</option>
      
      
      </select>
      <label for="dateOfBirth">申請者名<span style="color: red;font-weight:bold">*</span></label>
      <select name="name" id="id_child" class='dependent-selects__child' required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>選択...</option>
       <option value="宮元会長">宮元会長</option>
                  <option value="宮元社長">宮元社長</option>
                  <option value="監査役">監査役</option>
                  <option value="取締役">取締役</option>
                  <option value="松本　嘉朗">松本　嘉朗</option>
                  <option value="韓">韓</option>
                  <option value="西村　英治">西村　英治</option>
                  <option value="杉田　哲朗">杉田　哲朗</option>
                  <option value="南　洋志">南　洋志</option>
                  <option value="大西　美香">大西　美香</option>
                  <option value="竹田　有香">竹田　有香</option>
                  <option value="田川">田川</option>
                  <option value="長崎　義則">長崎　義則</option>
                  
                  <option value="島田　亮">島田　亮</option>
                  <option value="樋口　優子">樋口　優子</option>
                  
                  <option value="前川">前川</option>
                  <option value="島田　航">島田　航</option>
                  <option value="ジェシー">ジェシー</option>
                  <option value="ドウエン">ドウエン</option>
                  <option value="ヒエップ">ヒエップ</option>
                  <option value="木下">木下</option>
                  <option value="岡本">岡本</option>
                  <option value="三宅">三宅</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        
        <label for="label">使用部門<span style="color: red;font-weight:bold">*</span></label>
      <select name="usingDepartment" id="usingDepartment" required>
      <option value="管理部">管理部</option>
      <option value="営業部">営業部</option>
      <option value="業務部">業務部</option>
      <option value="製造部">製造部</option>
      </select>
      <label for="part2"> 購入品<span style="color: red;font-weight:bold">*</span></label><br>
      <input type="text" id="PurchasedItemForm3" name="PurchasedItemForm3" value="" required >
      <label for="label">会社クレジット・デビットカード<span style="color: red;font-weight:bold">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="" required >
       <label for="label">個人立替金額<span style="color: red;font-weight:bold">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="privateCost" name="privateCost" value="" required >

    
     
        <script>
                  updateList = function() {
                  var input = document.getElementById('myFile');
                  var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
                  var children = "";
                  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
                    children += '<li>' + input.files.item(i).name + '</li>';
                  }
                  output.innerHTML = '<ul>'+children+'</ul>';
                  }
               </script>
      <label for=" ">使用目的<span style="color: red;font-weight:bold">*</span></label><br>
      <input type="text" id="remarksForm3" name="remarksForm3" value=""  required>
      <label for="part6"> 領収書添付ファイル</label><br>
      <input type="file"onchange="javascript:updateList()" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>
      <input type="hidden" id="fileData" name="fileData" />
      <input type="hidden" id="mimeType" name="mimeType" />
      <input type="hidden" id="fileName" name="fileName" />
       <p>選択したファイル名：</p>

      　<div id="fileList"></div>
      <div id="output" ></div>
      <div id="progressbar" >
      <div class="progress-label" ></div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit"  value="送信" onclick="iteratorFileUpload()"　 > 
      </div>
      <!-- <td colspan="2"><span><?= message ?></span>  -->
      </div>
      </form>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var numUploads = {};
         numUploads.done = 0;
         numUploads.total = 0;
         
         // Upload the files into a folder in drive
         // This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
         function iteratorFileUpload() {
             var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;
         
             if (allFiles.length == 0) {
                 alert('請求書書添付してください。!');
             } else {
                 //Show Progress Bar
         
                 numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
                 $('#progressbar').progressbar({
                 value : false
                 });//.append("<div class='caption'>37%</div>");
                 $(".progress-label").html('アップロード処理中!画面閉じてないでください。');
                  alert('送信完了!');
         
                 // Send each file at a time
                 for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
                     console.log(i);
                     sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
                     
                 }
             }
         }
         
         function sendFileToDrive(file) {
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function (e) {
                 var content = reader.result;
                 console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
                 var currFolder = 'Something';
                 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolder);
             }
             reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         }
         
         function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
            console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
            numUploads.done++;
            var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc });
            $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
            if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
               //uploadsFinished();
               numUploads.done = 0;
            };
         }
      </script>
      <script>
         function fileUploaded(status) {
           document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
         }
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

### UPDATE

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your HTML&Javascript side and Google Apps Script side. Can I ask you about the detail of your script? In your Javascript, `google.script.run` is used. But in your Google Apps Script, only `doPost` is used. I cannot understand your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: Perhaps I missed them but I don't see any scriptlets in your html so why are you using create template and evaluate

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for replying to my post. I have updated full my code. Can you help me check? Thank you

Comment: @Cooper  Thank you for replying to my post. I have updated full my code. Can you help me check? Thank you

Comment: @Tanaike I will explain my code as follows, I use Google's HTML to get customer information. The customer information I save to Google sheet. As for the attached file, I save it to google drive.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, what is `showDialog()`? Do you use `showDialog()`? And, in your script, the file is sent with `google.script.run`, and the text data is sent with the action of the submitted form. Are you required to use this method? And also, for example, in your HTML `form` is not enclosed. From this situation, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script. In your question, how about testing your situation using a more simple script? By this, the issue might be able to be easily confirmed. If you cannot test using a simple script, I apologize.

Comment: By the way, I think that the reason for your questions 1 and 2 is that FileReader is run with the asynchronous process. Please be careful about this. And, about your question 3, how about separating this from your questions 1 and 2.

Comment: Have you logged `fileName` and `type` to see if that is where the error comes from?